# 07/08/2015 em São Paulo/SP - Encontro (Festa de Graduação) da comunidade SOpt 5.0

Tags: debate, meetup

Após o sucesso do encontro SOpt (Portugal) não está na hora de promover o encontro 5.0 (Brasil) ?

Olhando os posts dos encontros antigos vi que o número de "Stackers" foi relativamente baixo.

Será que o @Gabe não consegue alguns brindes como camisetas SOpt , agendas entre outros?

**EDIT:** Vou reunir informações de lugares e datas para nosso evento.

**EDIT 2** : como esse meeting vai ser mais descontraído deixo como sugestão o [Blue Pub](http://www.thebluepub.com.br/)

**EDIT 3 :**

DATA DEFINIDA: 07/08

LOCAL : [The Blue Pub](http://www.thebluepub.com.br/) - Alameda Ribeirão Preto, 384 - Bela Vista, São Paulo - SP

HORÁRIO: 19h

**Stackers interessados**

São Paulo, dia 07/08, até o momento:

- [Cigano Morrison Mendez](http://www.facebook.com/cigano.m.mendez)
- Victor Stafusa
- Wellington Avelino
- Math
- Luiz Vieira

Link do evento no Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/events/910536662336069/

MG e regiões :

- Delfino
- emanuelsn

Curitiba :

- rray

**Resumo em fotos do encontro**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Da esquerda para direita [Luiz Vieira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/73/luiz-vieira), [Math](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3117/math), [Cigano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2999/cigano-morrison-mendez), [André](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/30319/batrakius), Jéssi, [Daniel](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4816/daniel-gomes)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Da esquerda para direita [Daniel](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4816/daniel-gomes), [Cigano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2999/cigano-morrison-mendez), [André](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/30319/batrakius), [Luiz Vieira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/73/luiz-vieira), [Wellington Avelino](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/10315/wellington-avelino),  [Math](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3117/math).

Comment: Se houver brindes é bom que mande para Portugal também! :P

Comment: Estamos esperando o @Gabe aparecer, hahahaha.

Comment: Em qual cidade gostaria de marcar ?

Comment: @emanuelsn, se tiver 10 pessoas de MG e outras de SP fazemos 2 encontros no mesmo dia, podemos fazer um hangout.

Comment: 2 no mesmo dia? Seria bem legal. kk

Comment: Seria melhor dias alternados para possibilitar que gente de outros estados se conhecessem também. Sou do RJ. Mais algum carioca?

Comment: @papacharlie sou de volta redonda, mas atualmente moro em Indaiatuba

Comment: @Math, não me pergunte o motivo, mas sempre pensei que você era de Portugal.

Comment: Da pra ter brindes sim!

Comment: Olha Belzonte aqui, mais alguém?

Comment: poderíamos fazer aqui na minha Foz do Iguaçu para aproveitar e fazer um Turismo, tem cataratas, compras no Paraguai, usina de Itaipu, Polo astronomico, eco museu, museu de cera, conhecer a Argentina ( não tem muitos atrativos além dos barzinhos) a cidade tem tantos atrativos....

Comment: Gostei do Blue Pub. Pode ser lá também.

Comment: Só vou se for em algum lugar barato. A minha grana está curta e o saldo na minha conta é negativo.

Comment: @Delfino - Não sou de BH, mas se conseguirmos um número bom de pessoas, eu consigo chegar com +1 ou 2 pessoas.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, tem alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino Ainda não, mas vou pensar em algo...

Comment: tranquilo, posta aqui depois!

Comment: Beleza, sendo em SP tranquilo kkkkk, trabalho na Avenida santo amaro, pra chegar na região central/paulista ou metrôs é facil.

Comment: @emanuelsn, Podemos combinar aqui em BH, vou mandar uma copia para uma colega aqui de BH que tem uma pizzaria se ela pode nos receber.

Precisamos aumentar este número aqui em Minas.

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino, não é melhor abrir uma resposta como "Wiki da Comunidade" e o pessoal ir colocando informações relativas ao encontro na cidade. Ou mesmo uma resposta por cidade, mas como Wiki da comunidade, assim dá para todos contribuírem conforme sua região.

Comment: @Delfino, não sei como faz.

Comment: Eu vou fazer um postagem para Minas, já que já uma para São Paulo.
Para fazer basta criar uma resposta para cada região, marcar a resposta como "Wiki da Comunidade", logo abaixo da caixa de edição no canto direito.

Comment: @Gabe não se esqueça de mandar para Portugal :P

Comment: Sou do RS e me interesso também.

Comment: Quanto aos brindes, o pessoal que estiver organizando os encontros pode me enviar um email com os dados (onde, quando, quantas pessoas) e eu posso ver o que dá pra fazer.

Comment: @Gabe, vou mandar o e-mail com a quantidade que temos até agora e com local e datas

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino Ótimo! Ter o local e data com antecedência é mais importante que o total de pessoas, então não se preocupe se a lista de presentes ainda não estiver finalizada.

Comment: Pessoal, estou desconfiado que não estarei em BH no próximo mês.

Comment: @VictorStafusa , consegue dia 7/8? A todos, ao fecharmos a data podemos colocá-la no título e daí eu coloco a publicação em destaque, para aparecer no boletim da comunidade e quem sabe atrair mais usuários.

Comment: Parece que o Delfino se mudou para Fortaleza, ou seja, o encontro em MG está temporariamente suspenso por força maior :P

Comment: @Gabe, será que vai rolar os brindes?

Comment: Trabalho nesse horário, mas me interessei - posso?!

Comment: @DanielGomes, claro que pode! o evento é para todos, da uma olhadinha aqui http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4096/10315

Comment: Eu chegarei mais tarde um pouco... esperem por mim!

Comment: Se quiserem melhorar o título fiquem a vontade, só mudei para tentar dar mais destaque no boletim

Comment: Pena ser numa sexta feira, moro na "roça" e não dá tempo de sair do trabalho e chegar em sampa.

Comment: @gmsantos, no próximo seria bom se o pessoal falasse antes que ai dava pra marcar de sábado

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino só hoje que vi que o tópico entrou em destaque ;)

Comment: @gmsantos, putz :(, nos próximos vou pedir pra colocarem em destaque senão vamos ter poucas pessoas sempre.

Comment: /cc @Math hahaha

Comment: @gmsantos só hj viu que entrou em destaque ou só hj que viu a publicação graças ao destaque?

Comment: Só vi hoje que estava em destaque @math

Comment: @DanielGomes, não achei o André por aqui... depois edita com o profile dele.

Comment: É impressão minha ou o Math está c/ um bigodinho ridiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiculo :D :D :D

Comment: @bigown HAHAHAHAHAHAA

Comment: @bigown estou! hahahahahaha

Comment: @Math fala que é chopp escuro que ficou, fica melhor :D Acho que ficou com inveja do cavanhaque do Bruno :D Ainda bem que eu não vou pra vocês não verem minhas coisas ridículas :D

Comment: Poderia rolar todo mês um desses, no próximo um lugar menos caótico HAHAHA, uma mesa estava valendo mais que uma barra de ouro.

Comment: @bigown Esse bigode também tinha no ano passado.

Comment: Sério que ninguém (dos que não foram) percebeu que as duas fotos não foram tiradas no mesmo local do bar? É que rolou um *defrag* na galera a certa altura do happy hour... #tudumtss #nerdalert #piadaruim

Comment: @LuizVieira hahahaha, tinhamos o risco de ir ao banheiro e ter que ficar em pé depois, hahahahaahah

Comment: @bigown Aquele meu cavanhaque já era, agora tenho uma *barba* ridícula :D Pena que não fui pra registrar na foto :)

Answer (score 7):

## Chopp in Sampa

Minha sugestão. O primeiro encontro que teve por aqui foi no [Rhino](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiE67LdtczGAhVChZAKHQXFALE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rhinopub.com.br%2F&ei=PY6dVcTYKcKKwgSFioOICw&usg=AFQjCNE1voCP3bLDKfg38l-4GOxyc60a1g&bvm=bv.96952980,d.Y2I), mas lá acho muito barulhentão. Queria algo que a gente pudesse conversar sem berrar um com o outro.

Minha sugestão é a gente ir beber umas no [All Black](http://www.allblack.com.br/). Pra quem gosta de pub irlandês, é um bar fantástico, com dois ambientes: um mais silencioso e outro mais animado.

Como a grana tá curta, minha sugestão é irmos no dia 7/8, a partir das 20h. E vamos combinar o treco direito desta vez. [Quem tem Facebook me adicione](http://www.facebook.com/cigano.m.mendez) pra gente se comunicar e não ficar uma coisa desencontrada. Qualquer coisa eu abro o evento lá. Fica até melhor.

O que acham? (comentem aí)

---

**EDIT**

Coloquei o evento dia 7/8 no The Blue Pub, a partir das 19h. [O link do evento no Facebook está aqui](https://www.facebook.com/events/910536662336069/).

Vejo vocês lá!

Comment: Conheço o all black é bem interessante mesmo, chegando em casa vou colocar mais 3 opções.

Comment: Não seria melhor de sábado?

Comment: @Math, só não marquem de domingo please.

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino com ctz não o/

Comment: @Math, você tem em mente sábado a noite?

Comment: Opa! Eu curti a ideia! :) Sexta-feira dia 31/7 é uma boa data pra mim.

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino acho que seria melhor, será que seria problema para alguém? todo mundo prefere sexta?

Comment: Pode ser sábado também. O problema é que sábado é mais cheio.

Comment: Pra mim é indiferente...se combinar sábado tranquilo! @Math

Comment: Sábados a tarde pra mim é bem difícil por causa de aulas. A noite é possível, mas vai depender do dia. Ainda assim, eu prefiro as sextas. :)

Comment: Eai, vamos na sexta??

Comment: Turma, marcaram um show da minha banda exatamente neste dia e horário. Alguém tem problema de não poder ir no sábado, 1/8, mesmo horário?

Comment: E se adiantarmos ou atrasarmos para a sexta-feira dia 24/7 ou 7/8? Sábado já é meio complicado, ai considerando que é mais cheio (e possivelmente mais caro), talvez valha a pena insistir em uma sexta-feira. De todas as formas, eu acho que consigo no sábado 1/8 se for a preferência.

Comment: Pode ser 7/8 também. Dá mais tempo de divulgar, até.

Comment: Fico com 7/8 o que acham? quando for decidido faço um edit na pergunta com a data

Comment: Eu também. 7/8;

Comment: 7/8 é ok pra mim. :)

Comment: Tb voto por 7/8

Comment: @VictorStafusa, consegue dia 7/8 ?

Comment: E ai rapaziada, vai rolar mesmo, certo? Que tal fecharmos o local? Pra mim tanto faz o All Black ou o Blue Pub (apesar de que no All Black a entrada é mais barata, segundo o que consta nos sites, enquanto que o Blue é mais perto do metrô...).

Comment: @LuizVieira Pois é... o dilema que estávamos comentando em chat é que no Blue pelo menos a entrada e consumível. Por mim marcamos no Blue e faço o convite do evento hoje no Facebook.

Comment: Beleza então, @CiganoMorrisonMendez. Blue tá valendo. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira, o blue pub não tem mais reservas, podemos ver o allblack?

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino Claro!

Comment: Chegarei lá pelas 20h30 ~ 21h. Esperem por mim :)

Comment: @Math Chego mais ou menos neste horário, um pouco antes.

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino Mudou mesmo o lugar? Tá na hora do **edit 4** na pergunta... ;)

Comment: @DanielGomes Mudou. Blue Pub agora. Veja o evento no Facebook.

Comment: Eu estava preocupado com a mensagem do @WellingtonAvelino - *"blue pub não tem mais reservas, podemos ver o allblack?"* - isso se resolveu?

Comment: @DanielGomes, será no blue pub, chego por volta das 18:40/18:50

Comment: É Hoje heim galera!

Comment: É hoje! Partiu encher o pote!

Comment: No caso de alguém passar só por aqui, eu já cheguei e peguei mesa no andar de cima (no fundo). Abs

Answer (score 4):

Mesmo que as capitais do sudeste sejam destino preferido,
gostaria de *trollar*, digo propor, umas cidadezinhas que andei descobrindo:

**[Mossoró](https://www.google.es/maps/place/Mossor%C3%B3+-+RN,+Brasil/@-5.2810083,-37.2371187,10.39z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x7ba06e074d5ce0b:0x46694ffe5df19ebe)**
[image: mossoró]
<sup><sub>alfredojunior.wordpress.com</sub></sup>

**[Schroeder](https://www.google.es/maps/place/Schroeder+-+SC,+Brasil/@-26.4102934,-49.0571896,12.04z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x94de965ba3f45981:0xb8bba035d013138e)**
[image]
<sup><sub>sergio parisi</sub></sup>

Pra não dizerem que estou viajando completamente na maionese,
lembro a campanha do Windows 7, feita no pueblito de [**Sietes, Asturias, Espanha**](https://www.google.es/maps/@43.43251,-5.366993,632m/data=!3m1!1e3).

[image]

Claro que agora é inviável e nem Mossoró ou Schroeder tem lhufas a ver com SOpt,
mas fica aí a [*minhoca na cabeça*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_munic%C3%ADpios_do_Brasil) pra imaginar a versão BR9.0.

Comment: Você existe ainda?

Comment: Os programadores Ruby gostariam que fosse em [Rubinéia, SP](http://www.cidades.ibge.gov.br/xtras/perfil.php?lang=&codmun=354450).

Comment: /\, hahaahahaha

Answer (score 4):

### FTSL - Curitiba 16, 17 e 18 de setembro

Não tenho nenhuma ligação com a organização do evento, sou apenas um entusiasta. Parace ser uma boa pedida de dispensa do trabalho ir em um evento de software livre e realizar um encontro com o pessoal do SOpt.

Ano passado eu fui tinha algumas pessoas de fora do estado que vieram ver as palestras/particiar das oficinas, como é em setembro, ainda da tempo do pessoal que é de fora se programar para vir, pela [página](http://www.ftsl.org.br/node/16) parece que vai ser no cefet que é próximo da rodoviária e tem shopping do lado.

Comment: Quem deu upvote é pq tem interesse? rs

Comment: Eu dei upvote apenas para apoiar :) É meio longe para mim, para mim não dá. Quem tiver interesse seria uma boa comentar aqui.

Comment: \o valeu o apoio @math.

Comment: Eu vou. Vou estar de férias (louvado seja o tranca-rua), e pela programação, parece que vai ser um evento bem bacana.

Answer (score 3):

### MG e regiões

### Local Sugerido

- [Pomodori Serra](https://www.facebook.com/PomodoriSerra)

#### Participantes pré-confirmados

- [Carlos Delfino](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/8039/delfino) (Belo Horizonte)
- [Emanuel Neves](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9067/emanuelsn) (Coronel Fabriciano, Disponível para ir BH)

Comment: Eu moro em Coronel Fabriciano. Caso exista outra pessoa da região interessada em ir pra BH, avisa aí.